# Text Underline when Hover over Image

Tags: php, css, hover, underline

I'm slowly understanding php but need some help please.
I would like the h1 tag in the .rel to underline, when you hover over the post thumbnail.
Could someone point me in the right direction please?

I found: 
[hover image and text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728121/hover-image-and-text-change) BUT NO ANSWER.
[Underlining in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109967/underlining-in-javascript) but not sure how the jquery works in my case?
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?295704-Change-text-hover-when-hovering-over-an-image but the a href is wrapped around the image and text.

I've read about mouseOver and mouseOut functions but unfamiliar with these!

My code in php

div id="boxes"

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="rel">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
<?php if ($mulderamanda_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following css:

```
.box > .rel > a.thumbnail:hover ~ h1 { text-decoration: underline; }
```

and add a class attribute:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="rel">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
<?php if ($mulderamanda_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?> 
   </div>
</div>
```

ps:
deleted the unmatched `</div>`.

Comment: amazing!! and all in css! Thank you very much @collapsar