# How can I change color of a select option with CSS on hover?

Tags: html, css

```
<select style="width:245px;">
    <option value="rseleccionar">Seleccione..</option>
    <option value="bs">Bienes Separados</option>
    <option value="bm">Bienes Mancomunados</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the blue color of default for another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS image hover change color of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971133/css-image-hover-change-color-of-text)

Comment: I don't want to change text color... Just the color about mouseover in the select

Comment: So you want the option background color needs to be change when the user mouse over is that correct

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17742187/5374294

Answer (score 2):

**Styling `select` and `option` tag is very limited.**

This is because the way they are displayed may change according to the browser/the OS. Think about what happens when you click a select tag on your phone. You don't get a dropdown list as expected on a desktop browser. So you couldnt style something universal as it doesn't *natively* display the save everywhere.

**Styling possibilities are:** mainly on the `select` tag but very restricted on the `option`. You could for example disable the native style of the select box:

```
select {
    appearance: none;
    /* may need vendors prefixes. */
}
```

**Other solution is:** jQuery plugins that simulate select box using other HTML tags:

- https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/
- https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox
- And all that Google may return you with keywords "jQuery select box" :)

Answer (score 1):

Option elements are rendered by the OS, not HTML. You cannot change the style for these elements.

Comment: True for `option` but `select` can be styled.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it'll work

```
<select class="hover_color" style="width:245px;">
   <option value="rseleccionar">Seleccione..</option>
   <option value="bs">Bienes Separados</option>
   <option value="bm">Bienes Mancomunados</option>
</select>

.hover_color:hover { background-color: red; border:1px solid red }
```