# Hover doesn't work on select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

Is there any way to support hover on option tag ? I want to change highlight color of option tag.

```
<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

I don't want to use ul li . Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Comment: You can't do it.. As dropdown have different behaviour on every OS. You can do it with CSS Framework. But, they also convert the option to other element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change color of a select option with CSS on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833019/how-can-i-change-color-of-a-select-option-with-css-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You actually can't style the option tags but here's a cool workaround where you can still use your select and option elements: https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

(Javascript)

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

[CSS]

```
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #b83729;
}
.select-styled:active, .select-styled.active {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-styled:active:after, .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #962d22;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.select-options li:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background: #fff;
}
.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

See the link for full code